# How to update document field in IBM cloudant nosql

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, nosql

I'm trying to update a single field in my document using BlueMix Cloudant Nosql. The problem I'm facing is that I'm just overriding the whole document and not updating the single item or list of items. What is the proper way to execute the HTTP PUT command to do this? I'm new to both JSON and Nosql.

```
{
"_id": "2c314478997815d6e4037c0b1a848678",
"_rev": "10-a965f79ad26a23796cd331e6b1a04378",
"organization": "BusinessName",
"email": "emailaddress"
}
curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" HTTP1.1 '<Address>/<db>/<document> -d '{
"organization": "New Data",
"_rev": "<rev_id>"}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant is based on the Apache-backed CouchDB project and the open source BigCouch project.

You can not do partial updates in CouchDB. Get the document, update locally and push the whole doc back using PUT and the right _rev